# Using ip link To Connect Multiple Chroot Jails

Tags: linux, docker, chroot

I've done some research online, and I'm not really finding any info about how to establish a communication link between two or more chroot jails. The "standard" seems to be just using a single chroot jail for sandboxing.

To put things into context, I'm trying to perform the basic functions of docker containers, but with chroot jails. So, in the same way that two docker containers can ping each other via IP and/or be connected on the same user-defined docker network, can this exist for two chroot jails?

**I understand that containers and chroot jails are different things, and I'm familiar with both. I just need to know if there is a way to link two chroot jails in a similar way to linking two containers, or if this is nonexistent and I'm just wasting my time**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing magic about Docker: it's just using the facilities provided by the Linux kernel to enable various sorts of isolation.  You can take advantage of the same features.

A Docker "network" is nothing more than a bridge device on your host.  You can create those trivially using either `brctl` or the `ip link` command, as in:

```
ip link add mynetwork type bridge
```

You'll want to activate the interface and assign an ip address:

```
ip addr add 192.168.23.1/24 dev mynetwork
ip link set mynetwork up
```

A Docker container has a separate network environment from the host.
This is called a [network namespace](https://lwn.net/Articles/580893/), and you can manipulate them by
hand with the `ip netns` command.

You can *create* a network namespace with the `ip netns add` command.  For example, here we create two namespaces named `chroot1` and `chroot2`:

```
ip netns add chroot1
ip netns add chroot2
```

Next, you'll create two pairs of [veth network interfaces](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/veth.4.html).  One end of each pair will be attached to one of the above network namespaces, and the other will be attached to the `mynetwork` bridge:

```
# create a veth-pair named chroot1-inside and chroot1-outside
ip link add chroot1-inside type veth peer name chroot1-outside
ip link set master mynetwork dev chroot1-outside
ip link set chroot1-outside up
ip link set netns chroot1 chroot1-inside

# do the same for chroot2
ip link add chroot2-inside type veth peer name chroot2-outside
ip link set netns chroot2 chroot2-inside
ip link set chroot2-outside up
ip link set master mynetwork dev chroot2-outside
```

And now configure the interfaces *inside* of the network namespaces.
We can do this using the `-n` option to the `ip` command, which causes
the command to run inside of the specified network namespace:

```
ip -n chroot1 addr add 192.168.23.11/24 dev chroot1-inside
ip -n chroot1 link set chroot1-inside up

ip -n chroot2 addr add 192.168.23.12/24 dev chroot2-inside
ip -n chroot2 link set chroot2-inside up
```

Note that in the above, `ip -n <namespace>` is just a shortcut for:

```
ip netns exec <namespace> ip ...
```

So that:

```
ip -n chroot1 link set chroot1-inside up
```

Is equivalent to:

```
ip netns exec chroot1 ip link set chroot1-inside up
```

(Apparently older versions of the `iproute` package don't include the
`-n` option.)

And finally, you can start your `chroot` environments inside of these
two namespaces.  Assuming that your `chroot` filesystem is mounted on
`/mnt`, in one terminal, run:

```
ip netns exec chroot1 chroot /mnt bash
```

And in another terminal:

```
ip netns exec chroot2 chroot /mnt bash
```

You will find that these two chroot environments can ping each other.
For example, inside the `chroot1` environment:

```
# ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK> mtu 65536 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
36: chroot1-inside@if35: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 12:1c:9c:39:22:fa brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 192.168.23.11/24 scope global chroot1-inside
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::101c:9cff:fe39:22fa/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

# ping -c1 192.168.23.12
PING 192.168.23.12 (192.168.23.12) 56(84) bytes of data.                
From 192.168.23.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Prohibited                

--- 192.168.23.12 ping statistics ---                                   
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, +1 errors, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

And they can ping the host:

```
# ping -c1 192.168.23.1                                    
PING 192.168.23.1 (192.168.23.1) 56(84) bytes of data.     
64 bytes from 192.168.23.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.115 ms

--- 192.168.23.1 ping statistics ---                       
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.115/0.115/0.115/0.000 ms
```

Of course, for this `chroot` environment to be useful, there's a bunch
of stuff missing, such as the virtual filesystems on `/proc`, `/sys`,
and `/dev`.  Setting all of this up and tearing it back down cleanly
is why people use tools like Docker, or [systemd-nspawn](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-nspawn.html), because
there's a lot to manage by hand.

Comment: Thanks for this, I upvoted, but don't have enough rep to have it show. I will try this, and see how it works.

Comment: Hey, -1 voter; any comment about the -1? I would be happy to fix up anything here you feel is inaccurate.

Comment: There's nothing wrong, people are just snobs and like to downvote. This is the only info I've seen on this topic, and your answer was very in-depth and helpful, yet people still downvote. Whatever. Also, the -n flag isn't recognized as running commands in a network namespace. Instead, you have to use ip netns exec <command to execute>. Found that out on here: https://blog.scottlowe.org/2013/09/04/introducing-linux-network-namespaces/

Comment: For the `-n` option, it depends on how old your `iproute` command is.  I've got 4.15.0, which has it. I've updated the answer to include the `ip netns exec` alternative. If you found this answer helpful, feel free to mark it as accepted.

Comment: Right, I figured as much. Thanks for the help. I accepted the answer. Also, since you seem fairly knowledgeable about docker, I have another question that you may be able to answer for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51255170/mounting-cgroups-for-resource-management-in-docker

Comment: Update: when trying to execute the `ip netns exec chroot1 /home/jail1 bash` command, AS ROOT, it doesn't work and just spits out: `exec of "/home/jail1" failed: Permission Denied`. Do you know what could be causing this?

Comment: Yeah, it looks like you've got an error in your command.  `ip netns exec <ns_name> <command>`.  In your comment, you have `/home/jail1` where you would expect to find a command, but I suspect that is a directory.

Comment: But in the original answer, you specify 3 parameters `ip netns exec chroot1 /mnt bash`. You only specify two parameters in your last comment, however. chroot1 is the namespace, and bash is the command, so I assume that /mnt is the location. I'm quite confused now.

Comment: Ha! Lookit, I made a typo. Let me fix that up. That's what I get for using netns names that look really similar to the command we want to run.