# Mounting cgroups for Resource Management in Docker

Tags: linux, docker, resources, cgroups

This is in reference to https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#limit-a-containers-access-to-memory. I have already created working containers, running Docker version 18.05.0-ce on a Raspberry Pi (64-bit) using Raspbian Jessie Lite (essentially GUI-less Debian Jessie).

The documentation claims that you can just pass memory/cpu flags on the `docker run` command. But when I try something like `docker run -it --name test --memory=512m container_os`, it says:

`WARNING: Your kernel does not support swap limit capabilities or the cgroup is not mounted. Memory limited without swap`

I get a similar message about not having cpuset mounted if I pass a cpu-based flag, such as `--cpuset-cpus`. This obviously means that I don't have these different cgroups mounted for Docker to manage resources correctly, right?

Now referring to https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/runmetrics/#control-groups, I read the section about cgroups, but it wasn't super helpful to my understanding of the situation. So rather than just trying random kernel commands, does anyone with experience have a step-by-step explanation of how to do this the right way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After quite a bit of research, I figured this out, in-case anyone else out there has this same problem.

In reference to https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/cgroups.txt, which is extremely helpful on understanding cgroups, a kernel with all of the proper support should have most of the cgroups for docker mounted by default. If not, there's a command to do so:

From section 2.1 - Basic Usage

"*To mount a cgroup hierarchy with all available subsystems, type:*

## mount -t cgroup xxx /sys/fs/cgroup

*The "xxx" is not interpreted by the cgroup code, but will appear in
/proc/mounts so may be any useful identifying string that you like.*

*Note: Some subsystems do not work without some user input first.  For instance,
if cpusets are enabled the user will have to populate the cpus and mems files
for each new cgroup created before that group can be used*."

For this particular case, however, trying to mount an individual cgroup, such as cpuset, results in an error saying that the "cpuset special device does not exist". This is because the devs of Raspbian Jessie 8 didn't configure the kernel to support the cgroups that Docker uses for resource management by default. This can easily be determined by typing the `docker info` command, and seeing this at the bottom of the output:

`WARNING: No swap limit support
WARNING: No cpu cfs quota support
WARNING: No cpu cfs period support
WARNING: No cpuset support`

These are all of the cgroups that are needed for Docker to manage memory and CPU resources for containers. Testing to see if your kernel supports something like cpuset is easy. If the file `/proc/filesystems` has an entry that says `nodev cpuset`, then that means your kernel has cpuset support, but if you're reading this then it probably means it's just not configured in your kernel. That would call for a kernel reconfiguration and rebuild however, which is not so easy.

With the right kernel configurations, it just works automatically like it seems from the Docker Docs.

Comment: Another useful resource, regarding issues with memory-swap capabilities, is this link here: https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/#your-kernel-does-not-support-cgroup-swap-limit-capabilities